# Find the matrix $M$ of $\phi$ in respect to bases $K$ and $B$

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

Let $V:=\mathbb{R}[x]\leq 2$ and $\phi:V\to \mathbb{R}^2$ a transformation $p(x)\to (p(1),p^{'}(1))$.
Find the matrix $M_R^B(\phi)$ for the bases $\mathcal{B}=\{1,x-1,(x-1)^2\}$ of $V$ and $R:=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ of $\mathbb{R}$.

I know there are a lot of similar questions, but i can't get my head around this one in particular, because normally I would check what vector $\phi(v_1)$ represents in the base $B$ and then compute a base change matrix, but I can't or at least I don't know how to represent $\phi(v_1)$ in the Base $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B=(P_1,P_2,P_3)=(1,X-1,(X-1)^2)$ be the vectors of the base B.

And $R=(e_1,e_2)=((1,0),(0,1))$ the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$

You just need to compute $\phi(P_i)$ for $i\in\{1,2,3\}$ and to express $\phi(P_i)$ as a function of $e_1,e_2$.

For example, $\phi(P_2)=(P_2(1),P_2^\prime(1))=(0,1)=e_2=0\times e_1+1\times e_2$

Thus your matrix will look like this:

$\begin{pmatrix}
* & 0 & * \\
* & 1 & *
\end{pmatrix}
$